# Convert a list to dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe, txt

Hello is there a way to split this dataset to dictionary where the word will be the key and the value will be a list of numbers separated with comma ?

```
content = 
['the 0.125 0.8542 1.253 \n',
'of 0.678 0.568 0.184 \n',
'that 0.565 0.897 0.267 \n']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content = [
    "the 0.125 0.8542 1.253 \n",
    "of 0.678 0.568 0.184 \n",
    "that 0.565 0.897 0.267 \n",
]

out = {c.split()[0]: [float(x) for x in c.split()[1:]] for c in content}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'the': [0.125, 0.8542, 1.253], 'of': [0.678, 0.568, 0.184], 'that': [0.565, 0.897, 0.267]}
```

---

If you want strings as values:

```
out = {c.split()[0]: ", ".join(c.split()[1:]) for c in content}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'the': '0.125, 0.8542, 1.253', 'of': '0.678, 0.568, 0.184', 'that': '0.565, 0.897, 0.267'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
dict(zip([i.split()[0] for i in content], [i.split()[1:]for i in content]))
```

**Output**

```
{'the': ['0.125', '0.8542', '1.253'],
 'of': ['0.678', '0.568', '0.184'],
 'that': ['0.565', '0.897', '0.267']}
```

**Explanation**

In this performant solution we are creating two lists by splitting the existing list of strings and then using zip to combine it and finally converting it to dict.